# Datanucleus: Bidirectional 1-N relation on supertype

Tags: java, database, entity, jdo, datanucleus

I'm trying to model the following relations in datanucleus:

```
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
@Discriminator(strategy = DiscriminatorStrategy.CLASS_NAME)
public class Item {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.NATIVE)
    private Long id;
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class Address extends Item {

    @Persistent
    protected Item owner;
    ...
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class Customer extends Item {

    @Persistent(mappedBy = "owner")
    @Join
    protected List<Address> addresses;
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class PointOfSales extends Item {
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "owner")
    @Join
    protected List<Address> addresses;
}
```

Both the `PointOfService` and the `Customer` class can have multiple `Address` relations.

The `Address` type's `owner` field on the other should reference the owning object (either `Customer` or `PointOfService`.

### These are the database tables:

[image: Database tables]

### This is the code [UPDATE]:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("Tutorial");

        PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
        Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();

        try {
            tx.begin();

            Address addr1 = new Address();
            addr1.setPostalCode("1210");
            Customer cust1 = new Customer();
            cust1.setFirstName("Test");
            // cust1.setAddresses(Arrays.asList(addr1));
            addr1.setOwner(cust1);

            Address addr2 = new Address();
            addr2.setPostalCode("3333");
            Customer cust2 = new Customer();
            cust2.setFirstName("sdgsdgs");
            // cust2.setAddresses(Arrays.asList(addr2));
            addr2.setOwner(cust2);

            pm.makePersistent(addr1);
            pm.makePersistent(addr2);

            pm.makePersistent(cust1);
            pm.makePersistent(cust2);

            addr2.setOwner(cust1);
            pm.makePersistent(addr2);

            PointOfSales pos = new PointOfSales();
            pos.setAddresses(Arrays.asList(addr2));

            // that's the place where the error occurs
            pm.makePersistent(pos);

            tx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (tx.isActive()) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            pm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Error occurs at `pm.makePersistent(pos)`

### This results in an error:

> javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Object "org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.entities.PointOfSales@16fdec90" has a collection "org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.entities.PointOfSales.addresses" yet element "org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.entities.Address@561868a0" has its owner set to "org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.entities.Customer@740d2e78". This is inconsistent and needs correcting.

Do you guys have any idea how to make this work in a way, that I can add an Address to a Customer, and the **Address' owner is the automatically populated** with the Customer.
And vice-versa of too: set the owner and it is **automatically added to the corresponding Customer**?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not define what objects you persist and what operation you perform to GET that exception? Clearly having an identity defined in "subclass-table" strategy will potentially cause issues depending on what strategy it uses behind the scenes, when there is no single table storing the root identity.

Comment: I updated the post with the code that causes the errror. What strategy do you suggest?

Comment: since an address can only have 1 "owner" and you are assigning an `Address` (addr2) to a `PointOfSale` (pos) and a `Customer` (cust2) then sh*t will happen. If you want an Address to be usable by BOTH at the same time then you have to change your model

Comment: If I would craft plain sqltables i would have a table 'item_addresses' containing both pks (address, item/customer/POS and a type definition/table name. This would allow me to map the owner to the correct item subtype. The question is: how do I implement such a table in JPO? I already have the @Join, I guess i could set the table name, but how could I also set the type column and make datanucleus understand what I want?